# Extract image from content and set it as the featured image

Tags: functions, hooks, content, actions

**The problem:**
I'm posting from the Wordpress iPhone app. When adding an image, the image shows up in the description itself, which I don't like.

**What I'm trying to do:**
Remove the image from the description and do one of the following (don't know the benefits of one option over the other):

1. Get the image source from the removed image and add it to a custom field. -OR-
2. Set the image as the featured image

I figure either one of those options would help me to isolate the image URL for use in my post templates.

**What I've tried:**
Literally everything under the sun. Right now I'm adding code to functions.php but would eventually like to make this a plugin.

I think the code below is way off, but I want to post it to show some of the attempts I've made:

I've added an action to run a function mpb_remove_post_image on content_save_pre ...

```
add_action('content_save_pre', 'mpb_remove_post_image');
```

Problem with that is I don't have access to the post_id (which I need in order to set the featured image) using content_save_pre so I have to get the image url and look for a post with the guid equal to the image src...

```
function mpb_remove_post_image( $content ){

    // strip slashes, I guess we need to readd slashes when we're done?
    $content = stripslashes($content);

    // get the first image src
    $image_src = get_first_image($content);

    // if there's an image src we can jam
    if(!is_null($image_src)){

        global $wpdb;

        // query the db for an attachment with this image
        //$thumb_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='$image_src'"));
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_parent FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid ='$image_src'");

        $thumb_id = $result[0]->ID;         
        $post_id = $result[0]->post_parent;

        // set the featured image
        mpb_set_featured_image($thumb_id,$post_id);
        // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumb_id );

    }

    // remove any images in the content
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);

    $content = addslashes($content);

    return $content;
}
```

the code above references this function I wrote to get the image...

```
function get_first_image($html){

    require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $post_dom = str_get_dom($html);

    // get the first image
    $first_img = $post_dom->find('img', 0);   

    // if any images then return the src attribute
    if($first_img !== null) {
        return $first_img->src;
    }

    return null;
}
```

And to set the featured image ...

```
// set the featured image
function mpb_set_featured_image( $thumb_id, $post_id ){

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumb_id );

}
```

I've also tried to add an action for save_post, but anything I do inside the function that runs seems to trigger another hook that runs save_post again so it turns into an endless loop.

Does anyone know (even if it's at a high level) what steps I can take to accomplish this? To recap here's what I want to do...

On inserting a post 1) get the first image src 2) set it as a custom field or set it as a featured image 3) remove the image from the post.

**edit** - I should mention the code I posted does work if you add the post through the wp admin. But not if you add it via the mobile app.

Comment: The GIUD will change with the next wp version, so getting the post ID through the GUID is not a good plan.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured this solution wasn't going to work. I was hoping there'd be someone who could look at what I'm trying to do and offer up another suggestion. I'm a newb at this so what I have so far is kind of hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Why not utilize two hooks, one before post saved and one after post saved?

content_save_pre : Function attached with this hook will remove image from content and store it in session/[transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

save_post : With this hook you will have id of post. Function attached with this hook will set featured image for the post with that id and delete session/[transient](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) data.

Alternatively, If you want to go with your approach, I think you should use `post_name`, instead of `guid`, to retrieve post id from database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's any use in your particular scenario, but might be worth checking out the get_the_image plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/

It checks multiple sources to try and find an image to display - according to the FAQ:

> How does it pull images?
>
> - Looks for an image by custom field (one of your choosing).
> - If no image is added by custom field, check for an image using the_post_thumbnail() (WP 2.9's new image feature).
> - If no image is found, it grabs an image attached to your post.
> - If no image is attached, it can extract an image from your post content (off by default).
> - If no image is found at this point, it will default to an image you set (not set by default).

Comment: Just re-read your question, and TBH I'm not 100% convinced this would be that much use to you...